# How to refer to object's field in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class `MainScreen` which gets instantiated at startup. How can I get a field of `MainScreen` object from another class without reinstantiating the class?

```
public class MainScreen {
  private String user;
  public String getUser() {
     return user;
  }
}

public class OtherClass {
  public void getTheUser() {
    MainScreen.this.getUser(); // Here I want to get the user from instantiated main's mainscreen
  }
}

public class Main() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainScreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: The `MainScreen` instance's `user` must be passed to `SomeOtherClass` in some way. Do you have multiple users?

Comment: Yes i have multiple users

Comment: Then like *TJ Crowder* says, you need to pass the reference of that particular `MainScreen` instance to your `OtherClass` . A constructor or a helper method in `OtherClass` would do

Answer (score 3):

Usually, by passing the `MainScreen` instance created by `Main` into `OtherClass` at some stage, for instance via the `OtherClass` constructor, and then having `OtherClass` use `getUser` to get the user.

A very much less ideal approach is to put a `public static` field on `Main` that you use to store the `MainScreen` reference, and then have `OtherClass` use that. Again: Not ideal, not least because it makes it harder to write tests for the classes and increases the coupling between the three classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
  MainScreen.this.getUser();
```

You can't reference `this` from another class. One of the way to get `User` from `OtherClass` is to pass it in constructor or setter method.

```
public class MainScreen {
    private String user;
    public MainScreen(String user){
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getUser() {
       return user;
    }
}
public class OtherClass {
    String user;
    public OtherClass(String user){
        this.user = user;
    }

  public String getUser() {
    return this.user; 
  }
}


public class Main() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String user = "user1";
      new MainScreen(user);
      new OtherClass(user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

```
public class MainScreen {
  private String user;

  private static volatile MainScreen instance = null;
  private MainScreen () { }
  public String getUser() {
     return user;
  }

  public static synchronized MainScreen getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MainScreen();
    }

    return instance;
  }

}

public class OtherClass {
  public void getTheUser() {
    MainScreen mainScreen = MainScreen.getInstance(); // Here I want to get the user from instantiated main's mainscreen
    mainScreen.getUser();
  }
}

public class Main() {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainScreen mainScreen = MainScreen.getInstance();
  }
}
```

Comment: the OP has *multiple users*